# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Check if a product is a subscription product

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'd like to know how to determine if a given WC_Product object $product is a subscription product or not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use their helper function which is probably the most complete:

```
if( class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Product' ) && WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription( $product ) ) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Or you could also use WooCommerce's `$product->is_type( $type )` check.