# Woocommerce direct checkout for subscriptions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know it’s possible to send customer directly to the checkout page by appending “add-to-car=product_id” to the checkout endpoint like this:

```
yourwebsite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=12345
```

I was wondering if it’s a way to do the same when a product has subscription options? I use Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin to manage subscriptions and it doesn't create a separate variant for subscription product.

Answer (score 1):

Based on these answers:

- [Woocommerce add to cart button redirect to checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592633/woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-redirect-to-checkout)
- [WooCommerce Subscriptions - Check if a product is a subscription product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979866/woocommerce-subscriptions-check-if-a-product-is-a-subscription-product)

You can create a PHP script to change the redirect url after adding a product to the cart *(by checking the product class type)*.

Furthermore, using the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` hook you have two parameters: `$url` and `$adding_to_cart` *(product object)*. [Here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-form-handler.html#source-view.799) you find the documentation.

Then:

```
// redirects to checkout if the product added to the cart is a subscription
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout_if_product_is_subscription' );
function redirect_to_checkout_if_product_is_subscription( $url, $product ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Product' ) && WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription( $product ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
        return $checkout_url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

*The code must be added to your active theme's functions.php file.*